# PHP array_merge key order

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Does it matter in what order the keys in an array array doing an array_merge, i.e. would the keys in the second array below override the keys in the first array:

```
array1 = array('username' => 'abc', 'level' => 'admin', 'status' => 'active');
array2 = array('level' => 'root', 'status' => 'active', 'username' => 'bcd');
```

? Or would the order of the keys have to be the same in the two arrays?

Comment: You could of saved yourself 5 mins by simple trying it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [manual](http://php.net/array_merge) states the answer to this question:

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns
>   the resulting array.
>
> **If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one.** If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.

So, yes the keys in the second array will overwrite the keys from the first one if the second array contains some of the same keys.

```
$array1 = array('username' => 'abc', 'level' => 'admin', 'status' => 'active');
$array2 = array('level' => 'root', 'status' => 'active', 'username' => 'bcd');

$new = array_merge($array1, $array2);

print_r($new);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [username] => bcd
    [level] => root
    [status] => active
)
```

So you can see that the keys from the second array overwrote the same keys from first one; the order of the keys in each array does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution that allows the use of a template array to define the output order. Missing fields are filled with `null` or as specified. In this example the `first` and `last` fields are filled with `---`.

Please take note of the highlighted text from the previous answer about numeric keys.

```
function array_merge_template($array1, $array2, $template, $fill=null) {
    $_template = array_fill_keys($template, $fill);
    return array_intersect_key ( array_replace ( $_template, array_merge($array1, $array2)) , $_template);
}
```

Input:

```
$array1 = ['username' =>'abc', 'level' =>'admin', 'status' =>'active', 'foo'=>'x'];
$array2 = ['level' =>'root', 'status' =>'active', 'username' =>'bcd', 'bar'=>'y'];
$template = ['first','level','foo','username','bar','status','last'];
```

Output:

```
/* array_merge($array1,$array2) */
[
    "username" =>  "bcd",
    "level"    =>  "root",
    "status"   =>  "active",
    "foo"      =>  "x",
    "bar"      =>  "y"
]

/* array_merge_template($array1,$array2,$template,'---') */
[
    "first"    =>  "---",
    "level"    =>  "root",
    "foo"      =>  "x",
    "username" =>  "bcd",
    "bar"      =>  "y",
    "status"   =>  "active",
    "last"     =>  "---"
]
```

Comment: Nicely done! I found this solution useful for dealing with JSON API data strings that changed at the source (fields dropped, or added) but needs to be inserted into a database table with prior field mappings.